SVG animation in Blazor is inconsistent
I am trying to include some SVG animation in a Blazor page and it seems that it does different things each time I run it.
I would like to know if there is something I am missing to make this work reliably.
Thanks.
Here is my test page:
@page "/animation"
@rendermode InteractiveServer

<h3>Animation</h3>

<svg width="1000" height="1000" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <rect width="30" height="50" x="10" y="10" fill="blue">
        <animateTransform id="rect-rot-1"
                          attributeName="transform"
                          begin="0s"
                          dur="5s"
                          type="rotate"
                          from="0 25 35"
                          to="90 25 35" fill="freeze" />
        <animateTransform id="rect-tran-1"
                          attributeName="transform"
                          begin="rect-rot-1.end + 1s"
                          dur="5s"
                          type="translate"
                          additive="sum"
                          from="0 0"
                          to="200 0" />
    </rect>

</svg>

<p />

@code {
}


I have tried testing it with both MS Edge and Firefox and they both give varying results:

both animations work as expected
only one animation works
the end effect of the rotation works but is not animated
no animation at all

I have found that, at least for rotation, CSS-based animation is more reliable in both browsers.

Interesting.
I can confirm your results, there is an interplay with Browsers and RenderModes I didn't expect.
I can "fix" it for Edge & Chrome with RenderModes Auto and Server:
<animateTransform id="rect-rot-1"
                  attributeName="transform"
                  begin="0.01s"
                  ...                   

I'm not sure why this works but Blazor places the svg elements in its virtual DOM, there may be some conflict between starting and complete-loading.
In FireFox the rotation works Ok but the vertical animation never shows.

I changed the name of the ids to avoid minus signs ("-") per @Robert Longson 's comment.  Your fix now works for FireFox as well.  Thanks.

Yeah, I didn't know about the naming either. It now works consistently, on all rendermodes.

With SMIL you must escape minus signs if you use them in id values. So the correct syntax for the begin attribute is:


<svg width="1000" height="1000" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <rect width="30" height="50" x="10" y="10" fill="blue">
        <animateTransform id="rect-rot-1"
                          attributeName="transform"
                          begin="0s"
                          dur="5s"
                          type="rotate"
                          from="0 25 35"
                          to="90 25 35" fill="freeze" />
        <animateTransform id="rect-tran-1"
                          attributeName="transform"
                          begin="rect\-rot\-1.end + 1s"
                          dur="5s"
                          type="translate"
                          additive="sum"
                          from="0 0"
                          to="200 0" />
    </rect>

</svg>



Alternatively just don't use - signs in id attributes.
The reason is that a - sign is supposed to indicate a time offset e.g. foo - 1s so you have to tell the parser you're not doing that.

...To parse an individual item in a value-list, the following approach defines the correct interpretation. In addition, Id-values and Event-symbols are XML NMTOKEN values and as such are allowed to contain the full stop '.' and hyphen-minus '-' characters. The reverse solidus character '' must be used to escape these characters within Id-values and Event-symbols, otherwise these characters will be interpreted as the full stop separator and hyphen-minus sign, respectively...


Using the minus signs seemed to work (sometimes) in Edge for some reason, but your comment makes sense.

Feel free to report the problem to Chrome's bugtracker
